# Active Model Serializers: exclude attributes when rendering as a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

### TL;DR

Using: `gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.7'`

Is there a way to include/exclude options from a serializer when included as a relationship? Something like this:

```
has_many :options, only: [:id, :name]
```

?

### Details

I have a serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer < BaseSerializer
  attribute :id, :name

  has_many :options
end
```

`Option` has its own serializer, which includes several other attributes

```
class OptionSerializer < BaseSerializer
  attribute :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

However, when rendered in the `Product` relationship, I get *all* the options from the serializer. But when listed as part of a relationship (instead of on its own), I only want `id` and `name` to be shown.  Like this:

```
{
  "products": [{
    "id": "704c5a2d-ef53-4cae-9d3f-132dc18c148a",
    "name": "foo",
    "options": [{
      "id": "704c5a2d-ef53-4cae-9d3f-132dc18c148a",
      "name": "bar"
    }]
...
}
```

If I override the relationship, I can get there:

```
def options
  object.options.select(:id, :name)
end
```

...but 1) this feels sloppy, and 2) this creates N+1 issues. I can also create a `NestedOptionSerializer` then use that to render, but that seems like overkill.

Is there a simpler/cleaner way of including/excluding attributes when a Serializer is included as a relationship? Something like this?

```
has_many :options, only: [:id, :name]
```

?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: great question, did you get some more info about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a second initializer, say `ProductOption` in which you'll define the attributes you want that relationship to let the `Product` serializer pass, in this case `attributes :id, :name`

```
class ProductOptionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id, :name
end
```

Then, back in `ProductSerializer`, specify this new serializer on the relationship:

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id, :name

  has_many :options, serializer: ProductOptionSerializer
end
```